# Problem in partial fraction decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions, rational-functions

Consider the following rational function which we want to decompose to partial fractions $$\frac{x}{x^3-3x+2}=\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}=\frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{Bx+C}{x^2+x-2}$$ Now when we multiply out we get the following expression $$x=A(x^2+x-2)+Bx(x-1)+C(x-1)$$ If we consider $x=1$ we obtain $$1=0$$ What is wrong here?

Comment: The denominator doesn't exist at $x=1$ in the original problem.

Comment: You only use the $Bx + C$ when you have an irreducible quadratic in the denominator, but here you can factor $x^2 + x - 2 = (x+2)(x-1)$.

Comment: The problem is $x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$, so your PFD should be $\frac{x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}=\frac{A}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{B}{x-1}+\frac{C}{x+2}$.

Comment: In the context of partial fraction decomposition do we consider irreducible quadratics those without integer roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{x^3-3x+2}=\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2+x-2)}=\frac{x}{(x-1)(x-1)(x+2)} = \frac{x}{(x-1)^2(x+2)}$$ $$= \frac{A}{x-1}+\frac B{(x-1)^2} + \frac{C}{x+2}$$

$$x = A(x-1)(x+2) + B(x+2) + C(x-1)^2$$

Now, when we test with $x=1$, we get $3B= 1 \iff B=\frac 13$

Comment: But why isn't the 2nd expression right away enough for partial fraction decomposition? Is it because $x^2+x-2$ is reducible over integers? What if it's not?

Comment: If you have a quadratic that is not reducible over the set of real numbers, meaning that if both roots of $ax^2 + bx +c$, are complex, then the quadradic is irreducible over the reals.

Comment: Yes, however my question is still not answered. Let me rephrase it in this way: while doing partial fraction decomposition when is it okay for me to leave the quadratic term in the denominator as it is without factoring it out further ?

Comment: That's what I'm telling you, a quadradic function with real roots (is hence factorable) can be reduced.  However, for $ax^2+bx+c$, whenever we have $b^2-4ac <0$, then you keep the quadratic as is, with the numerator,  $Ax+B$

Comment: Thanks for the clarified answer!